# Hello, Can you help me for issue? (ETH CONTRACT DEPLOY)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, remix-tests

I am learning to deploy contracts to improve myself. I copied a contract that was actually deployed and deployed it on the Goerli testnet. However, I have these parts and I wonder why. It has an outline part in the original, I don't have it. I have the settings part, it is not in the original. I also face the same problem when I copy other contracts. What is the reason of this?

[image]

this is what happens to my ca

and

[image]

There is an outline tab in the contracts deployed in the original and in the entire ethereum network. no in my ca.

Why? Whats the issue?

Comment: Did you verify the contract? What type of contract is it? an ERC20 or an NFT contract, something else...

Comment: Yes verified. ERC20 contract. Verified with plugin on remix

Comment: What's the address? Etherscan is a closed source third party explorer, so they could change their rules at anytime without warning. Also they don't update testnets with the same frequency than mainnet. Sometimes you just have to wait.